# Section [dcl.type.decltype] was recently introduced in draft N4791, but I can't find the GitHub pull request that originated this insertion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The section [[dcl.type.decltype]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype) was recently introduced in the C++ Standard draft N4791. It didn't exist in the previous draft (N4778). But I can't find the pull request that introduced this section in the Standard. Maybe a pull request is not the proper tool to insert a new section in GitHub, but I still believe there must be some kind of document that must be approved before such an insertion is made. I would appreciate if someone could help me finding this document, which I presume would be a paper in [this list](http://www7.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/).

Comment: "*I still believe there must be some kind of document that must be approved before such an insertion is made.*" Why do you believe that? The [information isn't new](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#simple-4); it's just in a different place. I mean, maybe there was a paper that suggested there should be a section specifically for `decltype`'s typing behavior, or maybe it was just some editorial reorganization.

Comment: I agree with that. But even so, wouldn't it be necessary some kind of approval before the insertion of a new section title in the Standard?

Comment: I guess the question I have is why does it *matter*? New standard versions move all kinds of things around. This is a trivial editorial change that in no way affects how the language actually works. So why is it important to find out why this particular thing got moved into its own section?

Comment: It's not that it is important. I'm just trying to understand how this process of updating the Standard is made through GitHub. My curiosity was aroused in this case because I could not find a pull-request for this insertion. But than, it dawned on me that such an insertion probably wouldn't require a pull-request, because as you said, this was a trivial introduction of a new section title in the spec. Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was changed in [commit 9b525539f0c7bf734be8e01db082fca775dbd028](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/9b525539f0c7bf734be8e01db082fca775dbd028), “[dcl.type.simple] Factor out decltype(e) wording into its own subclause.”  To me, this looks like a purely editorial change.  Such changes are continuously made by the editors of the standard.